# htaccess umlaute redirect gives 404 in microsoft edge

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, microsoft-edge

I have a working htaccess in utf-8 with RewriteRules including German Umlaute. No problem here!

A simple redirect with German Umlaute ends in an 404 Error in **Microsoft Edge**.

```
redirect 302 /foo /bäh -> will become www.example.at/bÃ¤h
```

All other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, even IE11!!!) do the redirect with the correct encoding.

Comment: seems like you should just percent encode this stuff.

Comment: @pvg The Apache `Redirect` directive already does %-encode the response (`Location` header) in this instance.

Comment: What do you do with `/bäh`? Is this a physical file, or are you routeing this URL somehow (further rewriting)?

Comment: when I write the redirect with %-encode, then it works, but is not "human readable", but always better then a 404-error